# apache directory index file not showing

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I want to do 2 things in htaccess:

1. Strip extension from php files
2. serve dir/index when url is site/com/dir/

current code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

/dir/ --> /dir/index be default apache behavior, but the rewriteRule break this logic.
How to set up rewriteRule for stripping extension from file and not break dir --> dir/index logic?

Comment: But which of these rules you expect to do the required redirect?

Comment: apache redirects to index of directory by default as far I know, one of these rules is preventing it and i dont know why

Comment: The file `/promotion/index.html` exists?

Comment: /promotion/index.php exists.
.htaccess inside /promotion/ dir also exists with "DirectoryIndex index.php"

Comment: `RewriteRule`s are evaluated before `DirectoryIndex`, so your last rule results in `promotion.php` (or even `promotion/.php` unless you have `DirectorySlash Off`)

Comment: so `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` strips extension from files but its also preventing application from pointing at dir/index.. do you know how I need to change this rule to keep stripping  extension (/index.php --> /index) and allow pointing at dir/index?

Answer (score 0):

updating

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

solved the issue